# Baking a texture as image sequecne

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, baking

I've got a procedural texture, and I have animated it by keyframing the uv co-ordinates. The animation lasts  250 frames, and I need to bake the texture for every frame so I can use it elsewhere. I had no issues baking the texture for any single frame, but can't figure out how to bake the texture for all 250 frames into an image sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a plane.
2. Connect your texture to emission brdf in the plane's material
3. Add a camera above 2 meters the plane and make output size to equal width and height with desired resolution
4. Set it to orthographic and scale it to match the plane
5. Enable the emission pass and disable combined
6. In the compositor connect the emit pass to file output
7. Render as animation.

Repeat this for each kind of map if you have more than multiple maps.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply, I just tried your approach, it seems to work, but I already wrote a script to batch bake for the full interval that doesn't require additional objects like planes cameras etc. I was just wondering if there was a more straightforward way like the single texture case. Would you know anything about that? P.S  Im marking your workaround as the answer anyway as it seems to get the job done